# How to check whether all files inside a project are saved or not in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in static code analyzer tool. I need to scan many projects using my tool. My requirement is to check whether all the files inside my project are saved before i scan the project with my tool. 
I know how to check whether an individual file is saved or not. I am using the following code and it is working fine.

```
if(window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor().isDirty() == true) {
     MessageDialog.openInformation(this.window.getShell(), "Message", "Please save the file before you scan it.");
     return false;
}
```

But how to check for all files in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will help you:

```
    IEditorReference[] ref = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
    .getActivePage().getEditorReferences();
    boolean isDirty = false;
    for (IEditorReference iEditorReference : ref) {
        if (iEditorReference.isDirty())
            isDirty = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am getting "[Lorg.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;@7bc1fd7e" as the value in "ref". How to check whether all the files are saved from this reference value? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code is working fine. But lately, I noticed a glitch. If my project goes out of sync (like addition  or deletion of any files) then the code will break. I think isDirty() checks not only whether the file is saved or not, but for complete sync. What to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IDE.saveAllEditors` to do a complete check for open editors using files in your project, confirmation and save:

```
IProject project = .... your project

boolean confirm = ... ask for confirmation flag

boolean canceled = IDE.saveAllEditors(new IResource [] {project}, confirm);
```

`IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE` in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin,

Comment: I will try this. Thanks! @greg-449